# Selenium: Running the test suite in parallel (Not cross-browser-testing)

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, selenium-grid2, xdist

I would like to run a selenium test suite in parallel.(Or distributed mode)

(30 tests in the suite, would like 3 threads running in parallel with a total of 30 tests executed when finished, no repeated test)
I just want to test against Chrome browser. I do not want to test on other different browsers.
Will want to run locally and in CI pipeline.

I'm using Python + Pytest and potentially xdist (3 threads). Is it just a matter of instantiating a webdriver instance for each process and they can work independently and in parallel with no contention?
Does it make sense to use selenium grid with three nodes with the same configuration.(Is this overkill)
Does this mean each node will run 30 tests?
Or will it result in each node running 10 tests?

What is the best approach for this?
Thanks in advance.